# How to run a function concurrently with matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, matplotlib-animation

I am building a GUI that takes in sensor data from the raspberry pi and displays it onto a window via matplotlib animation. The code works fine, except when being run on raspberry pi, the matplotlib animation takes some time to execute, which momentarily blocks the sensor reading GetCPM that I'm interested in. How can I make both these programs run simultaneously without one clogging the other, I've tried the multiprocessing library, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Note: The sensor data that I'm plotting does not have to have a high sample rate, its the sensor that I'm displaying on label that does.

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import numpy as np 

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

import math
import datetime as dt
import time
from collections import Counter
import random as rn

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import threading as td
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

style.use('seaborn')
limit = np.array([5])

# Initialize Pressure Figure 

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()

x1, y1 = [], []
x2, y2 = [], []

TOT = []
CPM = 0


def GetValues(i, x, y, ax):

    volts2 = rn.uniform(3,6)

    x.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H: %M: %S.%f'))
    y.append(float(volts2))

    x = x[-50:]
    y = y[-50:]

    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, color= 'k')

    ax.fill_between(x, y, limit[0], where=(y > limit[0]), facecolor='forestgreen', alpha=0.7, interpolate=True)
    ax.fill_between(x, y, limit[0], where=(y < limit[0]), facecolor='darkred', alpha=0.7, interpolate=True)

    ax.set_xticklabels([])


def animate(i, x, y, ax):


    volts = rn.uniform(2,8)

    x.append(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H: %M: %S.%f'))
    y.append(float(volts))

    x = x[-50:]
    y = y[-50:]

    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(x, y, linewidth=1, color= 'k')

    ax.fill_between(x, y, limit[0], where=(y > limit[0]), facecolor='forestgreen', alpha=0.7, interpolate=True)
    ax.fill_between(x, y, limit[0], where=(y < limit[0]), facecolor='darkred', alpha=0.7, interpolate=True)

    ax.set_xticklabels([])

def GetCPM():

    global TOT, CPM 

    temp = 1

        # Test Case

    if temp == True:
        TOT.append(True)
    else:
        TOT.append(False)

    TOT = TOT[-2750:]
    count = Counter(TOT)
    CPM = count[True]

    return CPM



class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

#   If you want to customize the icon of the tk window, only accepts .ico 
        #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="iconname.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Pressure")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = GUI(container, self)
        self.frames[GUI] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(GUI)

    def show_frame(self,cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

        
class GUI(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig1, self)
        canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        canvas2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig2, self)
        canvas2.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        #Initialize label as self.

        lbl = tk.Label(self, font = ('Sans Serif', 40, 'bold'), 
                                background = 'purple', 
                                foreground = 'White') 
        lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

        def update():
            ll = GetCPM()
            lbl.config(text = "CPM = {}".format(ll)) 
            print(dt.datetime.now().strftime('%H: %M: %S.%f'))
            lbl.after(20, update) 

        update()



# interval determines the speed at which data is recorded, 1000 = 1 second
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()

    t1 = mp.Process(target=GetCPM)
    t1.start()
    t1.join()

    ani_1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate, interval = 500, 
                                    fargs=(x1, y1, ax1))
    ani_2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2, GetValues, interval = 500, 
                                    fargs=(x2, y2, ax2))

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Process(target=GetCPM)` runs `GetCPM` only once - it will not repeate `GetCPM` in some loop. You would have to use loop inside `GetCPM`. And you would have to run `t1.join()` after `app.mainloop()`

Comment: `Process` runs function in separated memory so it doesn't share variables with main process - and you have to use `Queue` to send values from this process to main process. But this means that in main process you have run some loop which will be periodically receive value from queue - and you can do it using `after()` like in `update()`. And sometimes it is easier to do all in main process using only `after()` without `Process`

Comment: So just to be clear, my current code only calls Process once, the changing values on the label is due to the GUI function? And if I were to loop the process and setup a Queue communication between ```update()``` and ```GetCPM()``` that would solve it?

Comment: normally when you run `GetCPM()` then it is executed only once - and the same is when you run `Process(target=GetCPM)` - it runs `GetCPM` only once. It doesn't use extra loop to run `GetCPM` many times. If you want to run code in GetCPM many times then you have to use loop `while True` inside `GetCPM` - and then `Process(target=GetCPM)` also will run it all time.